# Помогите доделать парсер для битрикс

Tags: php, парсер, битрикс, csv

Скрипт создает каждый раз блок заново, не зависимо от того был он уже спарсен или нет. Он должен проверять на изменения csv файл и если их нет, то ничего не делать. Соответственно если есть парсить только их.  Я не понимаю как это реализовать (я новичок в битриксе и php).

Код нужно просто вставить в консоль битрикса. Файл csv ([ссылка](https://github.com/0-Pirate-0/CSV)) положить в папку upload. И добавить инфоблок с этими свойствами:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#!/usr/bin/php
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] = "/home/bitrix/www";
$DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];

define("NO_KEEP_STATISTIC", true);
define("NOT_CHECK_PERMISSIONS", true);

require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
set_time_limit(0);

//пишем код
require_once 
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php';
$handle = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/test.csv', 'r');
if ($handle) {
$counter = 0;
$keys = array();
$data = array();
while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    $counter++; 
    //удаляем из прочитанной строки все символы переноса
    $buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '', $buffer); 
    $str =explode(';', $buffer);
    if ($counter==1){
        $keys = $str;
    }
    else{
        $el = array();
        foreach ($str as $key=>$item){
            $el[$keys[$key]] = $item;
        }
        $data[] = $el;
    }
}
if (!feof($handle)) {
    echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
}
fclose($handle);

CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');

foreach ($data as $key=>$el){
    $bs = new CIBlockElement;
    $PROP = array();
    $PROP['NAME'] = $el['name'];
    $PROP['PREVIEW'] = $el['preview_text'];
    $PROP['DETAIL'] = $el['detail_text'];
    $PROP['PROP1'] = $el['prop1'];
    $PROP['PROP2'] = $el['prop2'];
    
    $arFields = Array(
    'ACTIVE' => 'Y',
    'IBLOCK_ID' => 22, // Нужно написать свой id блока
    'NAME' => 'cmt_'.$el['id'],
    'XML_ID' => 'cmt_'.$el['id'],
    'PROPERTY_VALUES'=> $PROP,
    );
    if($PRODUCT_ID = $bs->Add($arFields)){
        echo $key.'.New ID: '.$PRODUCT_ID.'(XML_ID = cmt_'.$el['id'].')<br>';
    }
    else{
        echo $key.'.Error: '.$bs->LAST_ERROR.'<br>';
    }
}
}

require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/epilog_after.php"); //если ругается на него php, то комментим и дальше пользуемся
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы элементы не создавались каждый раз, вам нужно проверять их существование. Например, по `XML_ID`:

```php
$bs = new CIBlockElement;
foreach ($data as $key=>$el){
    $rsElement = CIBlockElement::GetList([], ['IBLOCK_ID' => 22, 'XML_ID' => 'cmt_'.$el['id']], false, false, ["ID"]);
    if (!$rsElement->Fetch()) {
        $PROP            = [];
        $PROP['NAME']    = $el['name'];
        $PROP['PREVIEW'] = $el['preview_text'];
        $PROP['DETAIL']  = $el['detail_text'];
        $PROP['PROP1']   = $el['prop1'];
        $PROP['PROP2']   = $el['prop2'];

        $arFields = [
            'ACTIVE'          => 'Y',
            'IBLOCK_ID'       => 22, // Нужно написать свой id блока
            'NAME'            => 'cmt_' . $el['id'],
            'XML_ID'          => 'cmt_' . $el['id'],
            'PROPERTY_VALUES' => $PROP,
        ];
        if ($PRODUCT_ID = $bs->Add($arFields)) {
            echo $key . '.New ID: ' . $PRODUCT_ID . '(XML_ID = cmt_' . $el['id'] . ')<br>';
        } else {
            echo $key . '.Error: ' . $bs->LAST_ERROR . '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```